# Is the Temperature of a Black Hole a Relative Thing?

Tags: black-holes

Because the laws of physics are the same in every reference frame, I assume the relativity of simultaneity [should] in principle apply to the black hole temperature and even evaporation rate. Surely a relativistically-moving observer  and the observer at rest will measure two different critical evaporation points of the black hole (so they don't initially agree when the event has happened until clocks are compared to see whose frame was dilated). I know that contractions on temperature has been proposed:

$$T = T_0\left(1 - \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2\right)$$

Does anyone know if these kinds of questions have been asked (which I expect somewhere they have) and if there is no difference in the evaporation time for the black hole, why is that so? And if there is, would that not also imply the black hole will appear cooler in one frame of reference and hotter in the other?

Comment: Temperature is as relevant as is time. From the Euclidean space sense, the temperature is nothing more than the period of the imaginary time. The closer you are at the black hole the greater the temperature of the black hole you measure while if you are at infinity, you measure the Hawking temperature. So yeah, the black hole will appear cooler to an observer further away from the black hole.

Comment: except, I am not talking about observers far away, I am talking about the Lorentz contraction a moving observer will experience opposed to one at rest. A consequence is the relativity of simultaneity, would state that one could even disagree when a black hole evaporates, so I am asking would this not imply a black hole may appear cooler depending on the frame of reference?

Comment: You are trying to apply Special Relativity to a case of General Relativity. In GR there is not such a thing as a global Lorentz transformation because the geometry is generally not flat. Instead, Lorentz transformations in SR become coordinate transformations (or diffeomorphisms) in GR. In any case, picking a frame of reference is equivalent to choosing a coordinate system. So I reanswer your question: Yes, the black hole will appear cooler in a (local) reference frame (be careful on what you mean by a reference frame in GR) and hotter in another.